# How to get a datakey in windowsforms 4

Tags: c#, winforms

Iam having a small problem, Iam working with windows forms

How do i get my datakey for a row that i have selected so i can delete it out of the dataset/table
I have seen many people that have same question and they get this slution:

```
  int ID = Convert.ToInt32(gridview.DataKeys[gridview.SelectedIndex].Values.toString());
```

But That doenst work for me.
I can type this:

```
 int ID = Convert.ToInt32(gridview.
```

then the intellisence doesnt give me datakeys.
so Thats the point where he blows out.
Do i miss a reference of something

Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 3):

[**DataKeys**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx) are for `GridView` the web control and not available in Window Forms. You need to have required columns in data source to bind with `DataGridView` (For Window Forms) and hide them if you do not want to show them.

**Binding the required column and hide the column**

```
 dgv.DataSource = source; 
 dgv.Columns["YourColumnName"].Visible = false;
```

**Getting value from hidden column**

```
string value dgvInHouseApp.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["YourColumnName"].Value.ToString()
```

Comment: how will i convert this one so that i won't use datakey value string strItemID = dataItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[x]["ItemID"].ToString(); @adil